Origin and grammaticality of "I like me ..."
A pattern:

I like me a good book.
I like me some fried eggs.

Most English speakers would not express ideas in this way. However, this vernacular is not uncommon in some parts of the United States.
Questions:

Does the word "me" in this phrase make it grammatically incorrect?
What is the known history of this phrase pattern?

I've never seen it in print before, and I'm curious about its origins. A search of the web via search engine and this website directly didn't yield any results.

Seems to mean for myself, akin to the French me-I in "Moi, je ..."

@YosefBaskin I don't think so: "moi je" is nothing but "je"; akin rather to the French "Je me les mange cru (eggs).": in that case ("datif éthique"), the added pronoun is meant to show some special interest in the action. I don't know what the added "me" means in AmE, though.

What about "Thou art like one of those fellows that when he enters the confines of a tavern claps me his sword upon the table " - Romeo and Juliet, III 1.

The phrasing is grammatical within the dialects that use it but seldom used in published writing.
Scholar Lawrence Horn, in a paper on the subject (1), calls this usage the "personal dative" pronominal in transitive clauses. He directly compares this to similar usages in languages like French, e.g., Je me prends un petit café [I take me a little coffee]. In French, that usage is commonplace; in English, it's frowned upon in standardized or professional usage but exists in some American dialects, including but not limited to the Southeast and Appalachia.
Note that this usage isn't the same as the reflexive pronoun, that is, it isn't functioning as a direct object and is not even functioning as an indirect object:

I like me a good book (personal dative pronoun)


(x) I like myself a good book (reflexive pronoun as direct object; doesn't work because myself would be a direct object but like doesn't take two direct objects without [and])


I like a good book for myself (reflexive pronoun as indirect object)

Instead, Horn claims that the usage is a non-argumentative dative, that is, they are not objects of the verbs. Rather, they are adjuncts emphatic of how preferable the statement is to the subject (what Horn calls a "conventional implicature ... of subject affect"). The personal dative appears far more often in the positive than in negation, and most instances of negation are qualified. Take this illustration (p. 183), where the positive statement is far more common than the negative:

As for more on the usage, looking up the "personal dative" will get you resources like the Yale Grammatical Diversity Project. This site cites Horn as well as other linguists studying the usage.
(1) Horn, L. R. (2008). I love me some him”: The landscape of non-argument datives. Empirical issues in syntax and semantics, 7(1), 169-192.

Published writing? It is only a speech thing. Of course, it is not written English unless a writer appropriates it to show that kind of speech. se prendre un café is not the same at all and certainly not the same register either. It's southern in general and southern AAVE.

@Lambie That's what I said. "In French, that usage is commonplace; in English, it's frowned upon in standardized or professional usage but exists in some American dialects, including but not limited to the Southeast and Appalachia."

No, Horn said it. And I am saying the professor is mistaken in comparing the two, they are not comparable. They just seem that way to someone who doesn't really know French because they look similar.

I’m not convinced there’s a fundamental difference with the reflexive pronoun here. There are cases where only one or the other is possible, but those are different constructions. The PD constructions where Horn marks only the reflexive as ungrammatical seem perfectly fine to me (e.g., “buy himself a pick-up for his son”, “needs himself a little more sense”). Especially in the second person, the non-reflexive pronoun is usually all but impossible to me (“have *you a merry little Christmas”). “Get you a man who…” is a common trope, but to me at least borderline ungrammatical.

@TaliesinMerlin  Thank you for this clear response.  It is good to see the word 'Dative' being applied to this context.  Forgive me for adding what is already, I think, implicit in your account.  It is worth stressing that ancient Latin and Greek nouns all had a separate form for nouns related as 'indirect' objects of a verb to connote the relationship to the action/event as beneficial or the opposite.  Arguably, the French pronoun 'lui' has some of that character.  I am not so sure that the French reflexive pronoun 'se' works like that.

@JanusBahsJacquet I agree with your judgement on those examples, but I partially agree with Horn’s point.  This construction (“personal dative” or whatever we want to call it) can use either myself or me in many cases, but whichever word it uses, it’s not acting in the usual sense of the reflexive pronoun — e.g. his example of “I’m gonna catch me some fish”, “I’m gonna write me/myself a letter”, the usual reflexive sense implies the fish are for the speaker’s consumption and the letter is to the speaker themself, while the personal-dative construction doesn’t imply that.

@PLL Agreed entirely. The construction and meaning is clear, I’m only disagreeing with the distinction that only the objective pronoun, not the reflexive, can be used in it.

@Tuffy The reflexive pronouns in French don’t distinguish accusative and dative (direct/indirect object) – only the third-person personal pronouns do.

@Janus Bahs Jacquet:- I did not make such a claim.  The words 'le', meaning 'him/it', and 'la', meaning 'her/it' are used as pronouns in French as in "Il la déteste (he hates her/it) and "Elle le déteste: (she hates him/it).  But then there is this word 'lui', which acts like a dative - that it, it is used in the way in which Romans used the dative case.

@Tuffy Yes, that’s what I said. Lui is the dative (indirect-object) form of the third-person singular personal pronouns il and elle, whereas le and la are the respective accusative (direct-object) forms. Plural ils/elles both have les as the accusative and leur as the dative. These pronouns all distinguish three case forms (subject/nominative, DO/accusative, IO/dative) plus a disjunctive form. The reflexive pronoun, conversely, doesn’t have a subject form and uses se for both accusative and dative, so it only has two distinct forms (accusative + disjunctive).

Note that the other personal pronouns also do not distinguish the accusative and dative forms; only the third-person pronouns do. The other singular pronouns have two distinct forms (plus the disjunctive): N je, A/D me; N tu, A/D te. The other plural pronouns go even further and merge all three case forms (and even the disjunctive), leaving them with only one form: N/A/D nous; N/A/D vous.

Correction: the end of the first comment above should say, “sit only has two distinct forms (accusative–dative + disjunctive)”.


Does the word "me" in this phrase make it grammatically incorrect?

Not really, but it depends on how far back you want to go to justify its use.
The "me" is the use of the Old English dative "me" = "for me" (or "to me") and
forms the equivalent of the current "for myself" or (to myself)
German, like English, is a Germanic language and this use of "me" is still current in German as we can see in the title of the book by Joseph Anton "Ich habe mir die Zeit geborgt" ( I have borrowed me the time") -> I have borrowed time for myself.
